# How can I make C++ in C?

Tags: c++, c, refactoring

Well, i was learning, again, a little bit of c and was with a little curious about how did the C++ inventor made it. And some facts lead me to the information, that he created it using pure C(obviously), so i was thinking if there is any source or anything that could help me to do things in C, that i can do in C++, like templates, namespace, class, reference and others it doesn't matter how difficult it is, i want to at least have more notion, so if anyone know a reliable source and well written i would be glad.

Comment: [Inside the C++ Object Model](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545)

Comment: Don't ask these type of questions. If you really want to use c++ features, then just use c++. If you want to use c++ features with C, find a library. If you want to create that library by yourself, then start doing it and ask questions about specific problems you're facing.

Comment: I think LLVM is capable of an IR->C transform

Comment: @sehe: There was such a thing, but it's no longer available for modern versions of LLVM/Clang.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal well sorry, but i want to learn how he made it, can't i?
Can't i learn more ways to make better codes in C? Can't i learn more things, don't get the hatred behind such a simply question, i want to learn more if i can't express such ideia here, i think that i'm in the wrong place...
never said that i wasn't going to use c++, just for use it's tools in c, just said that i want to learn more

Comment: @Troianos77: You're not going to learn a lot of useful things about C when studying C++.

Comment: Maybe read *Design and Evolution of C++*, by the language creator?

Comment: @Troianos77 Rather than be offended that your question was downvoted and closed, try to understand that it's not personal. It's just that your question is not of a type which is suitable for this site. You can read more about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and in the rest of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Newer members often assume that Stackoverflow is like a forum where you can discuss anything, but it isn't. It's a Q&A site with specific rules.

Comment: This could turn into a really interesting series of questions if you do a little bit of the work yourself upfront, look into compiler design from the high-level (not things like register allocation since you're translating to C), study Stroustrup's early works, etc. Then ask slightly more specific questions as you face challenges. ATM it's a bit too much like, "How do I get started?" and it puts the brunt of the focus on external links. Best answer -- just get started, check out these resources, and come back with some cool questions as you implement your project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many, many years back, the first C++ compiler, by Bjarne Stroustrup was a "frontend for a C compiler".

Today, it certainly isn't anywhere like that. Modern C++ compilers generate code directly from C++ constructs in intermediate form for the backend to process into machine code for the target. This allows the compiler to do a more direct job, and not rely on the C compiler "understanding" what is going on.

This page contains some reference material on the cfront: 
http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/index.html#cfront

That page also has links for the 3.0.3 archived sources as [unpacked](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/) and [compressed](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/cfront_3_0_3.tgz) form.

Note however that this release is 21.5 years old, and would thus, if it was a person be able to order alcohol in a US Bar after showing ID. This is NOT the modern standard C++ by any measure (and it may or may not generate code that is suitable for a modern C compiler, I have no idea)

With this quote to go with the 3.0 release from 1991:

> Bjarne Stroustrup notes, "A warning that Cfront 3 is pre-standard and
>   emphatically not recommended for use or further development might be
>   in place."

**Edit:**

I did download the code in the (compressed) link above. It certainly doesn't compile on Linux without effort. More effort than I am willing to spend, really. One of the problems is that it's pre-ANSI C, so the compile complains about various functions not being declared (for example `strcpy`, `strcat`, etc), and there are OS choices, none of which is Linux.

I also don't think it is necessarily the best place to start learning compiler techniques.